# Variables replacing into string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have string in format

> "sometext%1%-%2%blablabla%15%"

and collection of class Variable:

```
public class Variable
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I replace all substrings like `"%{ID Number}%"` with Value field of Variable which `Id` equals to `{ID Number}` (for example replace `"%1%"` with Variable Value field whose ID = 1) using `Regex.Replace` method or something similar?

Comment: I would use first Regex.Match to get all occurences of a number (use [\d]+ or something like it). Then it depends on how you stored those instances of Variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own match evaluator. This is untested, but the solution should look similar to this code:

```
String processed = Regex.Replace (rawInput, @"%(\d+)%", MyMatchEvaluator);

private string MyMatchEvaluator (Match match)
{
    int id = int.Parse (match.Captures[0].Value);
    return _variables.Where(x => x.Id == id).Value;
}
```

Where `_variables` is your collection of variables and `rawInput` your input string.

Comment: 2 little fixes: using Single instead of Where and we have remove all "%" symbols from match.Captures[0].Value

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
var data = new List<Variable>
{
    new Variable{Id = 1,Value = "value1"},
    new Variable{Id = 2, Value = "value2"}

};

var sb = new StringBuilder("sometext%1%-%2%blablabla%15%");

foreach (Variable t in data)
{
    string oldString = String.Format("%{0}%", t.Id);
    sb.Replace(oldString, t.Value);
}

//sometextvalue1-value2blablabla%15%
string output = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in to .Net that does this, but there are several implementations of this kind of functionality.

Check out [this blog post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/14/named-formats-redux.aspx) where he explores several implementations. The blog post is from 2009, but the code should be quite usable still :-)